# Google Tag Manger - no-script Code Not Found

Tags: headers, scripts, google, google-analytics, google-chrome

I am having trouble getting the "GTM no-script code not found: either missing or not in " issue resolved.

The GTM script is placed after the < head > tag. No issues.

However, when using the Google Chrome Tag Assistant, I keep getting the "GTM no-script code not found: either missing or not in " error.

Here is where I am placing the GTM noscript code in the header.php file:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-######"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->


<?php do_action( 'themename_after_body' ); ?>
```

I have also tried placing the GTM noscript code like this:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>


<?php do_action( 'themename_after_body' ); ?>
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-######"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix the Tag Assistant issue?